# Maven-scm-plugin: Do not commit a file unless it has changed

Tags: git, maven, maven-plugin, maven-scm

I currently use the `exec-maven-plugin` to run a java class that aims to generate a text file as output.

I commit then the resulted file to the git repository using the `maven-scm-plugin`.

The issue here is that sometimes the generated file is similar to the already commited one and this triggers a maven error when I try to commit the file (as expected).

I would like then to avoid commiting the file using `maven-scm-plugin` but cannot figure out how I can know whether it has changed or not.

I found that the scm-plugin's `diff` and `status` goals allow to get this information, but I am unable to store the result of the goals somewhere in order to parse it then set some boolean value that I can use to run or skip the commit.

May I have some help ?

Thanks !

Comment: Something which is generated shouldn't be checked in..Only the source out of which is has been generated..

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for you reply. I agree that in general, as long as we can generate something from a source, it is the source that should be checked in. But It turns out in my case that the generated file describes an application's metadata that may change between two consecutive versions. I need then to check it in everytime I create a git tag. Can you please advise a workaround to achieve this ? Thanks.

Comment: If you generate it somehow write a maven plugin which handles this correctly and you have solve everything...and never checkin generated code....

Comment: Did you find a solution to your issue?